# removing the default blue color on focus

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-storm, blackberry-simulator, blackberry-eclipse-plugin

I have a created a custom Button field , when the button is on focus default blue background  is coming , i want to remove that blue background . actually i am placing image on button and on image there are certain area which is transparent . when that custom button is on focus then blue background is displayed . i want to remove that blue background.

Thanks alot

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Override method

```
protected void drawFocus(Graphics graphics, boolean on) {
        if (on) {
                 //draw your own custom focus.
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

override method

```
public void onFocus(int direction) {}
```

and don't invoke super.onFocus in it

Comment: Still i am facing the same problem after removing super.onFocus() from onFocus(int direction){}